# Problema com chave SHA-1 em apk release e debug

Tags: android

Finalmente cheguei a uma versão *alpha* do meu app Android e resolvi envia-lo ao Play Store pela primeira vez. Como nunca fiz isso antes( sou novo no mundo de desenvolvimento Android), li alguns tutoriais e fui capaz de gerar um app assinado em meu Android Studio e deixa-lo pronto para o Play Store. Como se trata de uma versão alpha, criei um grupo de *alpha test* em meu Play Store console e adicionei meia duzia de amigos. Tudo funciona perfeitamente bem. Os testadores conseguem baixar o *app*, instalar e usar.

O problema começa quando preciso adicionar novas funcionalidades ao app. Obviamente o fluxo para isso é programar novas funcionalidades no android studio e assim que elas estiverem prontas gerar novamente o `.apk` assinado e fazer o *upload* para o Play Store, para que ele se encarregue de distribui-la aos meus alpha testers. Novamente, estou seguindo este fluxo e esta tudo dando certo.

Porém meu aplicativo usa algumas apis do Google, como o Sign In, Google Play Games e Google Maps. E algumas dessas necessitam da credencial de cliente OAuth 2.0 criada no Google Developer Console(que já foi criada por min e esta funcionando corretamente) para funcionar. Como muitos de vocês devem saber, esta credencial em particular necessita da chave SHA-1 do apk assinado para funcionar corretamente. Ai que vem o problema. Toda vez que estou programando novas funcionalidades para o `.apk`, tenho que ir na credencial de cliente OAuth 2.0 (no google *dev console*) e mudar a chave SHA-1 para a chave do `.apk` de *debug*. O que obviamente faz com que meus alpha testers que estão usando o *release* `.apk` não consigam ter mais acesso as apis do google implementadas no *app*. Por exemplo, o usuario não consegue mais logar no app via o Google Sign In. E novamente, quando acabo de subir a atualização para o PLay Store, retorno a chave SHA-1 para a chave do *release* `.apk` e tudo volta a funcionar para meus *alpha testers*.

Sei que deve ter uma maneira de contornar este problema, mas por ser novato com o Android não estou sabendo como fazer. Gostaria de alguma luz da galera mais experiente. Valeu =)

Comment: Thiago, se não estou enganado, você pode cadastrar mais de uma chave sha1 no [console do projeto](https://console.developers.google.com) não? Não sei nem se é necessário configurar algo extra no app, preciso verificar. Acho que apenas cadastrar a sua chave sha1 de debug e a sua de release no console deve resolver o problema.

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas pode ser que sim. Então, supondo que possa, penso que sua linha de raciocínio seria criar uma nova credencial de cliente OAuth 2.0 e configura-la com a chave SHA-1 gerada pelo Android Studio para o debug apk. Estou certo?

Comment: Então, se você cadastrar apenas o API key, não precisa fazer nenhuma alteração no app. Apenas gerar as duas SHA-1 baseada nos dois build types e cadastrar lá. Em relação ao OAuth 2.0 Client Ids, é a mesma situação. Acredito que você precise cadastrar os 3 artefatos criados no seu google-services.json (a API Key e os 2 Client IDS).

Comment: Acho que intendi. Só uma coisa, quando vc diz gerar as duas SHA-1 baseadas nos dois build types, isso quer dizer build>generate signed APK  e mudar o build type pra debug, certo?

Comment: Wakin, muito obrigado. Segui sua linha de raciocínio e deu certo.

Answer (score 4):

Quando vou trabalhar com alguma Api assinada costumo gerar o `.apk` de debug assinado, assim, terei apenas um `SHA-1`.

Para isso, coloque seu `.keystore` na raiz no seu Projeto (no mesmo nível da pasta app).

Em seu `build.gradle` (do módulo) adicione o seguinte:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        deployer{
            keyAlias KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
            storeFile file(STORE_FILE)
            storePassword STORE_PASSWORD
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            …
            signingConfig signingConfigs.deployer
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.deployer
        }
   }
 …
}
```

No arquivo gradle.properties adicione:

```
    STORE_FILE=../nomeDoArquivo.keystore
    STORE_PASSWORD=senhaDoStore
    KEY_ALIAS=seuAlias
    KEY_PASSWORD=suaSenhadoAlias
```

Com isto, seu `.apk` para debug será sempre assinado!

Para saber mais [segue a documentação](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)!

Comment: Hmm, gostei da sua abordagem. Vou tentar desta maneira =)

Comment: Thiago, fiquei com algumas duvidas. o .keystore que você fala pra copior pra raiz do projeto é o debug.keystore que fica na pasta .android? O storeFile é o path do debug.keystore ou o path do meu .jks gerado quando vou assinar meu apk? Valew

Comment: Cara, agora intendi. As constantes no grade.properties são referenciadas no build.grade

Comment: é o path do  debug.keystore! e o **STORE_FILE** é o caminho pra ele! Então, se voce colocar na raiz no projeto o caminho fica: **../nomeDoArquivo.keystore**.

Comment: Exato! Você pode deixar no gradle mesmo!!! Mas colocando no .properties ele não fica tão na cara!